# Allowing text to wrap around image

Tags: html, css

Not sure how to explain it, so [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk63G/). I'm trying to get the text to go next to the image, rather than either being completely on the next line, or only having one line of text in line with the image, and the rest of the lines underneath. How can I do this?

Code below:

```
<div class="main width">
    <div class="cont2">
        <div class="c5">
            <div class="head">Column Title</div>
            <div class="feat">
                <img src="http://scitechdaily.com/images/Hubble-Image-of-Elliptical-Galaxy-PGC-6240-150x150.jpg">
                <div class="featText">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="feat">
                stuff
            </div>
            <div class="feat">
                stuff
            </div>
            <div class="feat">
                stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:small;font-family:Roboto;vertical-align:middle;border:none;text-decoration:none;}
.width{margin:0 auto;width:84%;min-width:1000px;}
body>.main{font-size:0;}
.main{line-height:1.5;text-align:center;}
.head{background:linear-gradient(#444,#000,#444);padding:5px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;color:#FFF;}
.cont2{margin:0.5% auto;width:33%;margin-left:0.5%;display:inline-block;height:711px;}
.c5{background:#000;border-radius:7px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #BBB;}
.feat{width:100%;height:24%;background:#FFF;border:1px solid #BBB;border-left:none;border-right:none;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;}
```

Can this be done without floating the image?

Comment: Why are you avoiding floating?

Comment: I'm just not a fan. Floats have a habit of coming back to bite me in the ass a few weeks later as more things are coded in.

Comment: And avoiding them in this case will bite you even more.

Comment: Why can't I just use divs? If I can use them to create the layout of the page, then I should be able to use them to layout this column, no?

Comment: Posted the answer, but I won't recommend going this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to know solution without floats, here you go. But using `calc` is quite hacky solution and [will not work in every browser](http://caniuse.com/calc). And you have to know width of `img`. We have to include character space between two elements, as inline-block elements are not ideally next to each other.

```
.feat img{width: 50px; display: inline-block}
.featText{width: calc(100% - 54px); display: inline-block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the `img`:

```
img{
    float: left;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lk63G/1/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to avoid floats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the picture to align="left" like that:
`<img src="http://scitechdaily.com/images/Hubble-Image-of-Elliptical-Galaxy-PGC-6240-150x150.jpg" align="left">`

Comment: I think the align attribute is deprecated, so even if it does work, it's not something that I should be using.

Comment: True... does the picture always have the same size? In that case you could set the position of the text to relative and put it next to the picture using top:-150px and left:150px.  `.featText{width:50%;position:relative;left:150px; top:-150px}` Floating would be more elegant, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use floats

```
.feat img {float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NEWLE/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to avoid floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your css you'll get the first row of text next to the image and the rest below it, although it's not very pretty.

```
.featText{
display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

But perhaps it's a step on the way?